# Use site without SLL Certificate in httpRequest.Post

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, sll

It is possible to use sites without SLL certificate in httpRequest.Post?
I tried this: (but this doesn't work)

`httpRequest.Post("http://examplesite.com");`

I mean how to use sites http:// no https://
if it is possible please fix that code.
Thanks for help

Comment: If the site requires SSL (and each and every web site is requiring SSL these days, even for anonymous browsing), you have no option but to request it over secure sockets layer (https). This is not something that you can fix on the client side (where you run your code),

Comment: Additional to @OguzOzgul answer, this might be an XY problem. If you are getting errors due to certificate issues, you could fix those errors.